# Is it mandatory to use Runnable.run while calling done method from SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, future, swingworker

As part of learning SwingWorker I was going through the source code where I found the below code. I have a question regarding this.

```
private void doneEDT() {
        Runnable doDone =
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    done();
                }
            };
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            doDone.run();
        } else {
            doSubmit.add(doDone);
        }
    }
```

The above doneEDT is called from SwingWorker constructor as below,

```
public SwingWorker() {
        Callable<T> callable =
                new Callable<T>() {
                    public T call() throws Exception {
                        setState(StateValue.STARTED);
                        return doInBackground();
                    }
                };

        future = new FutureTask<T>(callable) {
                       @Override
                       protected void done() {
                           doneEDT();
                           setState(StateValue.DONE);
                       }
                   };

       state = StateValue.PENDING;
       propertyChangeSupport = new SwingWorkerPropertyChangeSupport(this);
       doProcess = null;
       doNotifyProgressChange = null;
    }
```

## Question

Why the `done()` method is wrapped inside the `Runnable` in doneEDT method?. The `done()` method can be called directly without wrapping it inside a `Runnable` right?. So I was thinking any advantage of wrapping it inside a `Runnable`?

So this question came in my mind.

Comment: It does not seem to make any sense as it is calling `run` directly. (Normally, a `Runnable` is passed to some other context to execute, such as `invokeLater`.)

Comment: But done() method can be called directly from doneEDT() method right? And this makes sense too right?

Comment: I missed the `if`; that's the difference. It can send the run off-thread. (In modern Java, `this::done` would be clearer.)

Comment: What you mean by "It can send the run off-thread"?

Comment: Examine what happens in the `else`.

Comment: Are you asking me to examine? If so I tried but no luck since it is hard to understand for me

Comment: If this thread is not the `eventDispatchThread`, it `submit`s the operation to run on that thread. (Note that this code would be dramatically clearer without the pointless attempted optimization and could be written entirely as `doSubmit.add(() -> setState(DONE))`.)

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating two different `done()` methods.  One is from `SwingWorker` that you're intended to override.  Nothing special with `Runnable` needs to happen in your implementation of `done()`, only your own code.  (A robust implementation of `done()` will check for `isCancelled`, possibly call `get()` if you're not calling it elsewhere and handle any exceptions that might have been thrown by the worker, etc.  But you don't need to wrap a `Runnable` to do any of that.)

The other method is `FutureTask`'s.  This gets confusing because SwingWorker itself uses a FutureTask to do the "real" work of handling concurrency.  The `FutureTask#done()` is *also* meant to be overridden by clients, but in this case the client is SwingWorker, not you.

When you call execute(), SwingWorker's `future` (the private instance variable of FutureTask) gets kicked into gear, and here's what happens:

- `future.run()` runs in a worker thread.
- `future.run()` calls the Callable passed in as you quoted above, changing the state to STARTED (which sends a property event) and calling `doInBackground`.  Your own worker code runs and returns a result.
- `future.run()` calls its own 'set' method to store the result and mark computation as complete.  It also calls a private method `finishCompletion`.
- `future.finishCompletion()` wakes up any other threads that have called SwingWorker's `get()` (and therefore have been blocked this whole time).  Those calls to `get()` can be returning the computation result to their callers at the same time as the rest of this list happens.
- `future.finishCompletion()` calls its own `done()`.  Normally this is an empty method, but as you've quoted above, SwingWorker made an override.  So *this particular* FutureTask `done()` does two more things:  first, it calls `SwingWorker#doneEDT()`, which simply calls `SwingWorker#done()` on the event dispatch thread.  That's the version of `done()` that you override in your subclass of SwingWorker.  And secondly, it changes the state to DONE which sends another property change event.
- `future`'s `finishCompletion()` returns to its 'set' method, which returns to `run()`, which does some housekeeping, and returns.  At that point, the worker thread is freed up for other things (new jobs, sleep, a hobby, whatever).

Your own involvement would only be with SwingWorker's `done()` if you wanted to subclass it.  Thanks to the juggling done by SwingWorker, your own override of `done()` is guaranteed to run on the event dispatch thread, so you can do things with Swing visual components safely.  Be aware that `done()` also gets called if the SwingWorker is cancelled, even if `cancel()` was called before `execute()` -- in fact, `done()` is called before `cancel()` returns -- so check the status accordingly inside your override.